# What happens if we connect two signal generators in series?

Tags: voltage, signal

While searching for a way to add multiple signals together, all the solutions i have come across included sources connected in parallel and a single opamp to make up for the attenuation caused by the averager circuit. My question is: Why cant we connect the signals in series like we do with dc batteries when we want their combined amplitude ?

[image]

Comment: You need some sort of synchronization if you want to add, say, two 5V 100Hz signals to get a 10V 100Hz signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the signals are not floating with respect to ground, so you can't do that - you would effectively short out one of them.

If you have something that is floating (such as the secondary of a transformer) you can certainly put it in series with some other voltage source, even one that has one side grounded.

It's also a convenient thing to do sometimes in simulation where all voltage sources are floating- for example to put a sine wave on top of another sine wave.

Comment: Some signal generators haven't floating outputs as Spehro says. Some *do float*. Its easy to measure...use your ohm-meter to measure resistance between output terminals and the power-plug ground. If its open-circuit, you have a floating generator that you can stack on top of another generator.